# difference between convert -quality and convert -resize and convert -density

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation, png

I'm trying to reduce file size of a .png in the terminal with Imagemagick `convert`

Does anyone know the difference between `convert -quality` , `convert -resize` and `convert -density` ?

`convert -quality` does not seem to work at all, whether you give it 99, 30, 10 or 1. It changes the file size sometimes even making it bigger!

This is a file of about 10MB. I am trying to bring it down to perhaps 1MB.

I am scared that `convert -resize` might do something to it such that if someone goes to print it out it will not be the size of an A4 page anymore.

Comment: Have a read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71205362/2836621

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since PNGs are lossless, compression on its own can only do so much, and reducing quality (with [`-quality`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality)) won’t help you cut the image file size to one-tenth its original size. Note that the value given with `-quality` is interpreted differently with lossy (JPEG etc.) and lossless (PNG) formats; for PNG, *increasing* the value will result in higher levels of compression.

The value set with [`-density`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#density) is an image attribute which specifies how many pixels fit in a given physical area (dots per inch by default). Changing this won’t affect the file size.

Sticking to PNGs, the only way to *drastically* reduce file size is to reduce the number of pixels stored in the image, using [`-resize`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#resize). Aiming for 10% of the original file size, you could start with a 10% geometry: `-resize 10%`. To keep the physical output size constant when printing, you should also decrease the density to 1/10 the original density.

Depending on the type of image, you might be better off converting to JPEG with a reduced quality level.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will switch to JPEG. I thought the P in PNG was for 'pocket' as in pocket-size and it was preferred for smaller files. Obviously not.

Comment: It stands for “portable”. In particular PNG files include features allowing typical cross-platform corruption to be detected.